# Can I connect to a GraphQL Subscribtion using Insomnia REST client?

Tags: graphql, graphql-subscriptions, insomnia

Insomnia now supports WebSockets. Therefore I was hoping that I can also use it to test GraphQL Subscriptions, since they are also using WebSockets.

I created a GraphQL request to open a new Subscription, but I always get the following response:

```json
{
    "errors": [
        {
            "message": "The response type is not supported."
        }
    ]
}
```

Am I doing something wrong or are GraphQL Subscriptions simply not a feature in Insomnia?

I checked the [Insomnia WebSocket Docs](https://docs.insomnia.rest/insomnia/websockets) as well as the [Insomnia GraphQL Queries Docs](https://docs.insomnia.rest/insomnia/graphql-queries) but couldn't find any info regarding this topic.

Answer (score 0):

The following solution worked for me, though it is far from ideal.
I use Apollo Server and prefer to use the build in Playground for subscriptions.

The template of a subscription looks like this:

```js
subscription UserCreated {
  userCreated {
    id,
    firstName,
    lastName
  }
}
```

You can then use the "repeat on interval" when using the Send button:

[image]